# Metamask onboarding/install redirect chrome extension/mobile

Tags: metamask

Is there a way to force / tell metamask to redirect to a specific page after the user has installed mobile app / chrome extension.

I already use metamask deeplink / onboarding library but there's no redirect at all.
The current process is the following
On desktop:

1/ The customer reach a page asking a eth account, onboarding library detect if metamask is installed

2/ If no metamask installed, onboarding lib redirect the user to chrome store extension in another tab

3/ Once the registration process if finished, user is "stucked" in this chrome extension page, and he need to go by himself to the tab asking his adress

On mobile

1/ Customer reach a page asking a eth account, onboarding library detect if metamask is installed

2/ If no metamask installed, i redirect the user to a metamask deeplink, which redirect him to the android store

3/ Once the registration process if finished, user is "stucked" on the app, and he need to go by himself to the tab asking his adress

Is there a way to add a redirection on step 3 for both process ?

Comment: did you ever solve this? If so what did you do? I am stuck in the same situation and I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dappUrl = "adljflajf.com"; // TODO enter your dapp URL. 
// For example: https://uniswap.exchange. (don't enter the "https://")
let metamaskAppDeepLink = "https://metamask.app.link/dapp/" + dappUrl;

window.open(metamaskAppDeepLink)
```

////you need to do this with user interaction or you get pop up block////

Use sweetalert like this

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

Swal.fire({
    title: 'changing to mobile',
    text: "you are open this dapp from a mobile device",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'open in metamask'
    }).then((result) => {
       if (result.isConfirmed) {
          Swal.fire(
            'now click on metamask!',
            'continue on metamask.',
            'success'
          ).then( window.open(metamaskAppDeepLink));
       }else{(window.location.reload())}
    })
```

do the same for other steps

Comment: Please where this goes, where user has no metamask on his mobile?